# Strassen's Square Matrix Multiplication

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to be able to implement a [Strassen's Multiplication method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) in Java. But I am not sure where to start. A lot of the information I found so far online has been extremely convoluted. Or, some of the ones that I can start to wrap my head around are only shown for 2x2 matrices. I need to be able to implement for an square equal matrices.

That being said, could someone please either clarify his algorithm, point me towards a good explanation, or formulate some sort of pseudocode that I might be able to follow? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might get the ball rolling sooner if you show us where you've got up to. Perhaps a link to the pages you've read already?

Comment: I've browsed the SO archives, looked at the Wiki, and found some random University PDF's/PPT slides. On my own, I was able to implement the basic matrix multiplication method already. I'm just trying to do the next step now.

Comment: So what is the issue with naively implementing the steps outlined in the wiki for it?

Comment: I'll probably try that. But it's for a 2x2 matrix only. I'm not sure how to expand that out.

Comment: apologies, it started out defining things in terms of n..  but yeah it drops to assuming 2x2 once it defines the elements of C. Hrrrrm, I wonder if it's recursive ??

Comment: 30s search indicates - yes? >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838838/recursion-in-strassens-algorithm

Comment: It is recursive. Once you understand how it works on 2x2 matrices, try it on 4x4 matrices, treating each 2x2 sub-matrix as an element in its own right. Then think about the recursion for square matrices whose dimension is a power of 2. Then consider that if you don't like the dimensions of the matrix you are given, you can always pad it out with zeros to increase its dimension.

Comment: mcdowella is exactly right. Many matrix multiplication algorithms (not just Strassen) use blocks, and are recursive. One reason for this approach is that the blocks increase your locality of reference, so you make better use of your CPU's caches for better performance.

Comment: @mcdowella, you are correct in formulating a recursive algorithm. Why not add that as an answer ;)

Comment: @vish4071 because I was just adding one more point to a topic already started by Lamar Latrell, and because the Original Poster had already read explanations probably better than any I would write in a small amount of time.

Comment: Thanks @mcdowella! That was the part I was missing in expanding from a 2x2. Last question though, how could I combine the 2x2 results into one complete matrix?

Comment: The wikipedia entry at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm tells you how to compute the four Ci,j entries of the result matrix (split into four parts) with a total of only seven multiplications. This is all you need to know to combine the answers. If your matrix started off as 2x2, then the Ci,j are just ordinary numbers. If it was e.g. 4x4 then the Ci,j are 2x2 matrices, and you use Strassen recursively to do the seven multiplications required.